# How to remove the active class from all children in a parent using Javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I have created 3 div having the same class in a parent , and on the child element i am adding the active class and on click of second child adding the active class again but this time i want to remove the active state for first element.
How can i remove it in effective way?

Here is my code

```
<div class="tab-div">
  <div class="tab">default</div>
  <div class="tab" >hover</div>
  <div class="tab">active</div>
</div>
```

Here is my javascript

```
var elements = document.querySelectorAll('.tab');
for (var i = 0; i < elements.length; i++) {
    elements[i].classList.remove('active');
    elements[i].onclick = function (event) {
        console.log("ONCLICK");
        if (event.target.innerHTML === this.innerHTML) {
            this.classList.add("active");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Lots of options, eg `$(".tab-div").removeClass("active")` or `$(this).addClass("active").siblings().removeClass("active")`.  Interesting that you've marked this jquery, yet have no jquery in your question!

Comment: Thanks and i need it using only javascript and i removed jquery tag..

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are not removing the `active` class from all elements when `click` event is triggered. So, what you can do is to loop over again to all the `div` and remove the `active` class on `click` event. I have created a custom function `removeClass()` that removes the `active` class on `click` event.

```js
var elements = document.querySelectorAll('.tab');
for (var i = 0; i < elements.length; i++) {
    elements[i].classList.remove('active');
    elements[i].onclick = function (event) {
        console.log("ONCLICK");
        //remove all active class
        removeClass();
        if (event.target.innerHTML === this.innerHTML) {
            this.classList.add("active");
        }
    }
}

function removeClass(){
  for (var i = 0; i < elements.length; i++) {
    elements[i].classList.remove('active');
  }
}
```

```css
.active{
 color: green;
}
```

```html
<div class="tab-div">
  <div class="tab">default</div>
  <div class="tab" >hover</div>
  <div class="tab">active</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 4):

I suppose it depends how many `div`s you will ultimately have, and if only one `div` should be active at a time, but I think it would be more efficient to just find the active `div` and remove the class from that one rather than looping through all of them e.g.

```
var oldActiveElement = document.querySelector('.active');
oldActiveElement.classList.remove('active');

var newActiveElement = event.target;
newActiveElement.classList.add('active');
```

Comment: Rather than `event.target`, use `this` (or `event.currentTarget`). `event.target` could be an element *within* the `div`, whereas `this`/`event.currentTarget` will reliably be the element the event was hooked on.

Answer (score 0):

Since all of them have a class called `tab`, make sure you remove the class or property of `active` from all the classes by targeting the class `tab` and it would remove from all without doing any loop. Then add the property to the current one that is clicked.

```
$(".tab").click(function(){
  $(".tab").removeClass('active');  
  $("this").addClass('active');
});
```

If the class is in the parent you can do sth like

```
$(".tab").click(function({
  $(".tab").parent().removeClass('active');
  $("this").parent().addClass('active');
});
```